# Implementing Edge Oriented Histogram

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, edge-detection, sobel

I am trying to implement edge oriented histogram: But there is a problem in the code, I am not able to figure out where   `val=fix((angles(i,j)-a_min)/(BinSize))+1;` is going Nan

I am taking 8 bins.
1. First I am finding gradient and angle using sobel operator.
2. Later I am having 8 bins (-pi/2 to pi/2  , as atan returns value between these two value), and I am binning the gradient magnitude according to the angles.

```
    im=imread('cameraman.tif');
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(im);
im=im2double(im);

sob_x=[-1,0,1;-2,0,2;-1,0,1];
sob_y=[1,2,1;0,0,0;-1,-2,-1];

im_x=imfilter(im,sob_x);
im_y=imfilter(im,sob_y);
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(im_x);
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(im_y);

im_edge=zeros(size(im));
angles=zeros(size(im));

[r c]=size(im);
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        im_edge(i,j)=sqrt(im_x(i,j)^2+im_y(i,j)^2);
        angles(i,j)=atan(im_y(i,j)/im_x(i,j));%angles are -pi/2 to pi/2
    end
end

subplot(2,2,4);imshow(im_edge,[]);

im_temp=im2bw(im_edge,80/255);
figure();subplot(1,2,1);imshow(im_temp);
subplot(1,2,2);imshow(angles,[]);

%calculating the histogram



No_bins=8;
H=zeros(1,No_bins);
BinSize=pi/No_bins;


a_min=-pi/2;
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        val=fix((angles(i,j)-a_min)/(BinSize))+1;
        if (val>8)
            val=8;
        end
        if(val<1)
            val=1;
        end

        H(1,val)=H(1,val)+im_edge(i,j);


end
end

H
```

Answer (score 0):

implemenetation of this 
`angles(i,j)=atan(im_y(i,j)/im_x(i,j));%angles are -pi/2 to pi/2` return Nan value in some pixles. You should try extract edge orientation at edge pixels.